# Series inequalities from Integration

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Given that Sum of the Numbers $(S_n)$ =$\sum\limits_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt r}$

By comparing to $ I_n =\int\limits_{1}^n \frac 1{\sqrt x} dx $

Show that $ 2{\sqrt n}-2$ ≤ $S_n$ ≤ $2{\sqrt n}-1 $

Question given in a Real Analysis module.

Comment: By estimating $$\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})^2 \sqrt{n+1}}$$ with telescopic terms you may show that $$2\sqrt{n}-\frac{3}{2}\leq S_n \leq 2\sqrt{n}-\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right).$$ You don't always need integrals to produce tight approximations.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Since $t \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt t}$ is decreasing over $(0,\infty)$, one has
$$
\int_{r}^{r+1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt t}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt r}\le \int_{r-1}^{r}\frac{dt}{\sqrt t},\quad r=1,2,\cdots,
$$ then one may sum from $r=1$ to $r=n$ then notice that $\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dt}{\sqrt t}=2\sqrt{n}-2$.